# Split dataframe by certain values in first column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
A          C1   C2   Total 

PRODUCT1   8    11   19
rs1        5    9    14    
rs2        2    2    4 
rs3        1    0    1
PRODUCT2   21   12   33
rs7        11   7    18    
rs2        7    3    10
rs1        3    1    4
rs9        0    1    1
PRODUCT3   2    11   13
rs9        1    6    7    
rs5        1    5    6
```

The column A is made of strings, I want to split my dataframe by the values in this column, specifically every upper word in it. Like this:

```
df1 = 

PRODUCT1   8    11   19
rs1        5    9    14    
rs2        2    2    4 
rs3        1    0    1

df2 = 

PRODUCT2   21   12   33
rs7        11   7    18    
rs2        7    3    10
rs1        3    1    4
rs9        0    1    1

df3 = 

PRODUCT3   2    11   13
rs9        1    6    7    
rs5        1    5    6
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: For me that looks like a messy dataset. The Product line is not necessary because that is just a summary statistics. Most probably it would be better to use pure python for data conversion. Afterwards you could use pandas to calculate all the statistics you want. Can you provide an example of how the raw data looks like ?

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['PRODUCT1', 'rs1', 'rs2', 'rs3', 'PRODUCT2', 'rs7', 'rs2', 'rs1', 'rs9', 'PRODUCT3', 'rs9', 'rs5'], 'C1': [8, 5, 2, 1, 21, 11, 7, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1], 'C2': [11, 9, 2, 0, 12, 7, 3, 1, 1, 11, 6, 5], 'Total': [19, 14, 4, 1, 33, 18, 10, 4, 1, 13, 7, 6]}) 

for key, group in df.groupby(df['A'].str.isupper().cumsum()):
    print(group)
```

prints

```
          A  C1  C2  Total
0  PRODUCT1   8  11     19
1       rs1   5   9     14
2       rs2   2   2      4
3       rs3   1   0      1
          A  C1  C2  Total
4  PRODUCT2  21  12     33
5       rs7  11   7     18
6       rs2   7   3     10
7       rs1   3   1      4
8       rs9   0   1      1
           A  C1  C2  Total
9   PRODUCT3   2  11     13
10       rs9   1   6      7
11       rs5   1   5      6
```

---

The idea here is to identify rows which are uppercase:

```
In [95]: df['A'].str.isupper()
Out[95]: 
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9      True
10    False
11    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

then use `cumsum` to take a cumulative sum, where `True` is treated as 1 and `False` is treated as 0:

```
In [96]: df['A'].str.isupper().cumsum()
Out[96]: 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     3
10    3
11    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

These values can be used as group numbers. Pass them to `df.groupby` to group the DataFrame according to these group numbers. `df.groupby(...)` returns an iterable, which lets you loop through the sub-groups.

Comment: Wow this is genius, it works perfectly. Thank you very much sir.